# Using subprocess.call - if exist an error save the error into a file

Tags: python, stderr, subprocess

I'm trying to save all errors in a file, and I can't find a solutions. I'm too newbie in python, please patience :D

In a "for" I have this line, and works fine, but can't log the errors.

```
knull = open(os.devnull, 'w')
kerror = open('/tmp/error.log','wb')

proc = subprocess.call(['7z','a', file-Zip, files],stdout = knull, stderr = kerror.write())
kerror.close()
knull.close()
```

Have I to add something in kerror.write(HERE) but I don't know what. Or maybe I'm doing this in a wrong direction.

Thank you !!!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should use "a+" mode to append new messages to an existing file, using "w" will overwrite it.

Secondly, error messages are text messages so you should not use "b" mode(which means binary).

FYI, you may want to use the handy `logging` module which is the best to handle logging-related tasks :)